# How to evaluate this function into power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am asked to expand $$
f(z)=\frac{z-1}{e^{i z}}, z_{0}=0
$$ into power series, while $z\in \mathbb{C}$

I got only to the form of $$ (z-1) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-iz)^n}{n!}$$ I am not sure what should I do with the factor of $(z-1)$

Comment: Maybe you can expand into a binomial and rewrite the summation?

Comment: should be $(-iz)^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just multiply it out, but there is an error in your expansion of the function. Observe that

$$e^{-iz} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!}.$$

You have

\begin{align}
f(z) &= (z-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!} = z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iz)^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}z^{n+1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}z^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}z^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n}{n!}z^n - 1 \\
&= -1 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{(-i)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-\frac{(-i)^n}{n!} \bigg)z^n
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$(z-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-iz)^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^nz^{n+1}}{n!} -1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^nz^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n(z^{n+1}-z^n)}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-iz)^n(z-1)}{n!} $$

Or

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^nz^{n+1}}{n!} -1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^nz^n}{n!}=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(-i)^{n-1}z^n}{n(n-1)!} -1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-i)^nz^n}{n!}=-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n\bigr(n(-i)^{n-1}-(-i)^n\bigr)}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-iz)^n(ni-1)}{n!} $$

Hope this helps. As always correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The final result is not a power series, you just moved $(z-1)$ inside the sum. What you have to do is shifting the summation index in one of your sums and add the two series afterwards.

Comment: @Gary  Thanks for the suggestion. This was incorporated and matches with the other answer.